# How to copy a Tab Page from one project to another with the related code (C# Winform)

Tags: c#, winforms

New to C# (as in never learned or used before) and learning as I go at work.

I have 2 projects nearly identical (different branches) and I'm trying to move a Tab Page from one project to more updated version with the code related to said controls in that tab page.

What's the best way to do it other than manually moving it line by line?

The  code related to the tab page buttons, text boxes, controls are scatterd over about 10 different forms. Is it even possible to do some simply copy paste that will take the whole tab as is and merge/add the code related to said controls?

I'm only familiar with C for embedded stuff, so my terms game for C# is non existent.

So far I've only figured how to copy the design part with all the correct properties but non of the code/events linked to the controls.

Comment: `The tab page buttons, text boxes, controls are scatterd over about 10 different forms` how did you do that ?

Comment: Small company.. previous guy. No one really knows C# or anything. So we write thing like we would in C. So things end up on different forms.. 4 years later it grows into a monster.  New here and trying to fix things to be a bit easier to handle.

Comment: you can copy the design part, but Visual Studio will never include the event codes. You will have to do that manually. About the scattering, you mean that the event codes are scattered througout different forms, right ? That will make things very hard for you I am afraid. You need to find them all and copy manually

Comment: Yea figured.. Thanks anyway. Doing it already. Shouldn't take more than a day just a bit annoying. Yes it's the events code that is all over the place.